# dimension of quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $f(x)=x^4+3x^3-x^2-4x-3$ and $g(x)=3x^3+10x^2+2x-3$
and $U = \{u(x)f(x)+v(x)g(x) | u(x),v(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$, find the dimension of quotient space $\mathbb{F}[x]/U$

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $M$ is a sub space of $V$, then $\dim (V/M)=\dim V - \dim M$. If I consider $\Bbb{F}[x]$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{F}$, its dimension is $\infty$. Please help me.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For any given polynomials $f(x)$, $g(x)$

$\{u(x)f(x)+v(x)g(x) | u(x),v(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$ $=$ the set of all the multiples of the GCD of $f(x)$, $g(x)$ (it is a principal ideal). Find GCD using the Euclid algorithm ( it involves (long) divisions with remainders). We get 
$$\gcd(f(x), g(x))= x+3$$
and so 
$$U= \{(x+3)\cdot u(x)\ | \ u(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$$

The map $\mathbb{F}[x] \to \mathbb{F}$
$$f \mapsto f(-3)$$
is a surjective $\mathbb{F}$-linear map with kernel the ideal $U$. Therefore we have the isomorphism of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces 
$$\mathbb{F}[x]/U \simeq \mathbb{F}$$
and so the dimension of the quotient is $1$.